# Major changes to Bitcoin since original paper

Tags: bitcoin-core, history, satoshi-nakamoto, whitepaper

Is there a history of the major changes/additions (as well as perhaps major proposals) to Bitcoin since the original paper by Satoshi? I realize of course that one can read through the BIPs and Bitcoin-Core release notes, but I was wondering if there existed a more concise historical "changelog" (or essentially a paper describing the facets of the current Bitcoin-Core implementation). The vast majority of Bitcoin (short) history resources that I can find are not at the level of specificity that I'm looking for (seeming to focus more on price history/external context), but reading through all the BIPs is perhaps more than what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I hope you know that the “paper” doesn’t really describe anything much about Bitcoin as a system, and is even completely incorrect in parts. It’s at best a short summary.

Comment: There is a list of all consensus rule changes: https://blog.bitmex.com/bitcoins-consensus-forks/ (This was released in 2017 but there hasn't been a consensus rule change since then, except for Taproot that has been locked in but not activated yet.)

Comment: Thank you @VojtěchStrnad, that's quite helpful! I'm certainly aware the paper is limited in its descriptions; is there some paper detailing Bitcoin as a system (and the history behind design decisions)?

Comment: Relevant: @David Harding's bitcoin white paper errata: https://gist.github.com/harding/dabea3d83c695e6b937bf090eddf2bb3